# ubuntu OS, g++, cannot find -lplplot

Tags: c++

Here's the problem:

I'm gonna use some scientific plotting in my C++ programs, and I find PLplot. 
Then I just typically do `apt-get install cl-plplot` and do `pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot`.
Then, I include the header file `#include <plplot.h>` in my code, and do `g++ -lplplot main.cpp`. It just returns "cannot find -lplplot".

However, I tried to locate or find plplot.so and get nothing! It's not in /usr/bin/lib or /usr/lib or anywhere else! I'm confused with that..

Anyone with any general idea about this type of error?

Comment: Run as root `apt-get install libplplot-dev` to install the development package (providing headers). Order of program arguments to `g++` is important: use `g++ -Wall -g main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplotd-c++)` at least.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I should link plplotd other than plplot.

Answer (score 1):

First search for plplot.h in your system. if it exist use -I flag for compile.
for example:
`g++ -I /path_to_your_file/ -lplplot main.cpp`